# How to prevent hard jumping and what is alternative to position: sticky?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Two questions:**

1. Focus on the part of 'Get early access' bar. It is positioned with position:relative and I want to have it sticky once you move to the 2nd section. I've tried to add helper with the same height in order to get smooth transition when I change the .class to fixed. But not working.
   This with helper in previous websites helped me but now it doesn't work and it really bothers me.
2. What would be alternative to position sticky which works in all browsers? In this particular case, how needs jquery to look like?

Thanks in advance.

```
/**
 * Zirelco
 * Custom JS functions
 */

jQuery(document).ready(function ( $ ) {
var  mn = $("#sticky-wrapper");
mns = "nav--scrolled";
hdr = $("#top-wrapper-v1").height();

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if( $(this).scrollTop() > hdr ) {
    mn.addClass(mns);
  } else {
    mn.removeClass(mns);
  }

});


$('.cookies .btn').on('click', function() {
    if ($('.cookies').css('opacity') == 0) {
        $('.cookies').css('opacity', 1);
    }
    else {
        $('.cookies').addClass('none');
    }
});

});
```

Comment: What if you add the height calculation in the if condition? `if( $(this).scrollTop() > $("#top-wrapper-v1").height() ) {`

Comment: I think the best option is to use `position: sticky` and a polyfill to ensure backwards compatibility. You'll get the benefit of the browser optimising and performing silky smooth sticking, while falling back to a tested and edge-case supporting framework. I'd recommend StickyBits: https://github.com/dollarshaveclub/stickybits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit V3

Try this Code instead of yours:

```
(function(selector) {

    selector = selector  || '#sticky-wrapper';
    var stickyWrapper = document.querySelector(selector)
    var stickyTrigger = document.createElement('div')
    stickyTrigger.classList.add('sticky-trigger')
    stickyWrapper.parentElement.insertBefore(stickyTrigger, stickyWrapper)

    var listener = function (e) {
        if (stickyTrigger.getBoundingClientRect().top < 0) {
            stickyWrapper.classList.add('sticky');
        } else {
            stickyWrapper.classList.remove('sticky');
        }
    }

    var onScroll = document.addEventListener('scroll', listener);

}('#sticky-wrapper'))
```

What this does is:

- create a `.sticky-trigger` element
- insert this right before `#sticky-wrapper`
- watch for `scroll` event of document
- check the `top` property of [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) of the `.sticky-trigger` element
- toggle the `sticky` class of `#sticky-wrapper` depending on the sign (positive or negative) of that `top` value

You don't have to change your HTML output at all

### Old V1

<del>You use the height of the `#top-wrapper-v1` `<section>` as trigger for the class toggle. But you totally forget the to calc the `<header>` height as well.
To prevent such mistakes just go for the top edge of the '#sticky-wrapper' as a trigger</del>

```
// $(window).scroll(function(e) {
//  if( $(this).scrollTop() > mn.offset().top ) {
//    mn.addClass('sticky');
//  } else {
//    mn.removeClass('sticky');
//  }
//});
```

### Old V2

<del>Because of the comment of the asker, this is an improved way of doing it.
In the previous example, the measurement of the `offset().top` of `#sticky-wrapper` is immediately set to `0` caused by `position: fixed`. In order to break this issue, we wrap the `#sticky-wrapper` in a trigger element, measure the `offset().top` of **that** element as trigger. This trigger element will remain in the document flow and will not be `fixed`</del>

HTML

```
<!--
<section id="sticky-trigger">
  <section id="sticky-wrapper" class="">
    <div class="container" style="position: fixed;top: 0;">
      Other content
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
-->
```

JavaScript

```
// var trigger = document.querySelector('#sticky-trigger')
// $(window).scroll(function(e) {
//   
//   if( $(this).scrollTop() > trigger.offset().top ) {
//     mn.addClass('sticky');
//   } else {
//     mn.removeClass('sticky');
//   }
// });
```

Comment: This helped me to add-remove class but unfortunately, the class once scrolled is immediately removed and after that again added. Do you maybe know the reason for that?